# How can I save result from groupby in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

I have a dataframe

| key1 | key2 | key3 | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | s2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | a | s2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | b | j6 | 1 | 1 |

and I want as result

| key1 | key2 | key3 | value1 | value2 | sum_value1 | sum_value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | s2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7 |
| 1 | a | s2 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | b | j6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

sum_value1 is the summation of values in value1 by grouping key1, key2, key3. And so for sum_value2.

How can I get this? Thank you!

What I used so far:

`df["sum_value1"] = df["value1"].groupby(["key1","key2","key3"]).transform('sum')`

Comment: I forgot to write the set, sorry. My set for grouping is ["key1", "key2, "key3"] and I want to sum value1 and value2.

Comment: What u have tried upto now?

Comment: @di1a Please post the code or statement which you have tried so far.

Comment: I don't get it...How you got sum_value1 as 5,5,1...What values you are adding such that you get total `5`

Comment: `df.join(df.groupby(["key1","key2","key3"]).transform('sum'))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use groupby and transform to return the sum of individual columns

```
df[['sum_value1','sum_value2']]=df.groupby(['key1','key2','key3'])[['value1','value2']].transform(sum)
df
```

```
    key1    key2     key3   value1  value2  sum_value1  sum_value2
0      1       a       s2      3       4       5          5
1      1       a       s2      2       1       5          5
2      2       b       j6      1       1       1          1
```